# Which U.S. online discount broker is the best value for money?

Tags: united-states, discount-broker, stocks

Which U.S. online discount broker is the best value for money?

Lower prices preferred, but I also like to be able to reach somebody by phone when help is needed.  24 hours not required, but after hours trading is a nice to have...

Comment: How is this not subjective?

Answer (score 5):

I agree, Schwab representatives are easy to reach and very helpful. I also like Vanguard for their low mutual fund fees, so I do my retirement stuff with them, but it took forever to get in touch with a representative just to ask a simple question.

Now that they are lowering their rates to 8.95 per trade (effective January 19th), the value for your money is even better.

Comment: I too am happy with Schwab. Once got a call from a representative from them because I had a smallish chunk of money just sitting in my account, and they wanted to make sure I knew about my options for cash-based investments.

Answer (score 4):

I am very happy with Charles Schwab.  I use both their investing tools and banking tool, but I don't do much investing besides buy more shares a random mutual fund I purchase 4 years ago

I did once need to call in about an IRA rollover and I got a person on the phone immediately who answered my questions and followed up as he said he would.

It is anecdotal, but I am happy with them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have at least $25,000, Wells Fargo is the place to be, as you get 100 free trades per account. I have three investment accounts with them and get 100 free trades in each a year, though I only ever actually use 10-20. i can't vouch for their phone service as I've never needed it, but free is very hard to beat in the "value for money" department.

Update: Apparently in some states the requirement is $50,000. However, they count 10% of your mortgage as well as all deposit and investment accounts toward that balance.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used them myself, but [Scottrade](http://www.scottrade.com/) might be something for you to look at. They do [$7 internet trades, but also offer $27 broker assisted trades](http://www.scottrade.com/online-brokerage/trading-fees-commissions.html#tab0) (that's for stocks, in both cases). Plus, they have [brick-and-morter storefronts all over the US](http://www.scottrade.com/locations/index.html) for that extra "I gotta have a human touch". :-)

Also, they do have [after hours trading](http://about.scottrade.com/media/facts/fact-sheet-scottrade-trading-website.html), for the same commission as regular trading.

Answer (score 0):

For self-service type online customers, OptionsXpress gives me far better trading features(like technicals advanced conditions) and tools, ACH money management & scheduling, fullfillment too. $9 stock trades.

I don't know if they yet share Schwab's (their new parent company?) commission-free ETFs getting so trendy nowadays.